# Ubuntu installer doesn't show my internal SSD when booted from usb

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation, mac, macbook

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 onto an early 2015 Macbook air running macOS Mojave. I've created a bootable usb with Ubuntu on it and can boot from the usb stick but can't install it. When I'm using the installer it skips the page for installation type and goes straight onto the one for 'Something else' without giving me the other options (e.g. erase disk and install Ubuntu - the option i want to use). This brings me onto a page just listing the usb i'm booting from - /dev/sda, /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, free space . All the other applications don't seem to recognise the ssd either. Other answers online suggested it might be something to do with RAID but I don't know what this is or how to enable or disable it.

Comment: Update: I don't think its an issue with RAID. Using "diskutil appleRAID list" in termianl returns "No AppleRAID sets found"

Answer (score 0):

i have no knowledge of macs, but concerning your mac it may be a "m2" ssd and in this case, there is a turnaround : when starting from an usb key, pressing F12 (on MAC ??) to get access to the boot device selection, as soon as you have the firts grub screen, you must edit the command line ("e" command) and add "nvme_load=YES",  before booting (replacing "quiet splash ---"

see details on this page here :

https://www.dell.com/support/article/fr/fr/frdhs1/sln299303/loading-ubuntu-on-systems-using-pcie-m2-drives?lang=en

(Dell but i suppose this will work for other machines)

hope this may help ...

Comment: Thanks but this isn't working. I've added this to command line on the grub screen but my drive still doesn't show up in the installation menu. I've looked up the ssd type for my laptop and it says that it uses MVME PCLe blades but uses apple specific pinouts that are different from readily available from M.2 PCLe standard blades. <http://www.ssd-for-mac.com/module/macbook-air-compatible-ssd.html>.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway and hopes this helps